# Is there any way to install full Ubuntu 22.04 on an old Laptop which does not have UEFI (Legacy Bios)?

Tags: 22.04

I have Dell XPS L502x which does not have UEFI. I tried to boot Ubuntu 22.04 on USB. It worked fine without any problem. When I tried to install it on SSD hard drive, after restarting, there were no operating system. The problem is related to UEFI. My bios is legacy.
Is there any solution to run full Ubuntu on this old laptop (2012)?

Which Ubuntu distro doesn't have UEFI support in its kernel?

Comment: There's no difference in the kernel between UEFI and legacy boots. Do you have Nvidia hardware?  If so, did you try booting with the "nomodeset" kernel parameter or in recovery mode?

Comment: I have a full install of Kubuntu on a SSD for UEFI boot. My old BIOS only 2006 laptop with only 1.5GB of RAM worked. I just added a BIOS grub boot of SSD to hard drive on old laptop. The difference with UEFI and BIOS is the version of grub boot loader. BIOS uses grub-pc and UEFI used grub-efi-amd64.

Comment: I use hardware as old as 2005 in my QA of Ubuntu Desktop (*and especially flavors*). Ubuntu Desktop will install on BIOS/legacy hardware, uEFI or Secure-uEFI equally; if the ISO is written to thumb-drive correctly (*as documented*), however you can write it to thumb-drive such that boot record is written to incorrect device (*thus won't boot*), and creating ESP is optional (*though default install will use it even if useless; unless `calamares` installer is used as used by some *flavors*). I do **not** see the uEFI as a problem **UNLESS** you wrote ISO to thumb-drive incorrectly!

Comment: Your description matches a QA install on the old hp 2005 box I mentioned earlier which had no issues with installing to, but bug reports mentioned what you did. I was able to re-create, but writing ISO incorrectly to thumb-drive, such that `ubiquity` was detecting machine as uEFI & thus didn't write legacy MBR which is required for BIOS machine. This however required a re-format of ISO during its write to media, thus how you write ISO to media really matters, or you can create media that will only boot on MBR, or only boot on uEFI/Secure-uEFI. If it's uEFI related I'd look at how you wrote ISO

Comment: @guiverc I use Rufus on windows 11 to write Ubuntu ISO to flash drive. I use MBR partition scheme as mentioned on https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#9-installation-complete. The problem is that after installation, EFI partition is created on my SSD hard drive.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop does create an ESP (*EFI System Partition*) by default, unless you go into *Something else* and specifically tell it not to (ie. *don't create/select one and none will be used, at worst you can a **warning** that the system **may not** boot*) however if you're using a BIOS/legacy/CSM or old machine, the ESP is not used & just expected where GPT is used (GPT being created in the EFI era). I'd ensure you `rufus` is updated (*older versions had issues with 22.04; but they usually resulted in failure to boot live, not install issues; sorry I don't use rufus`*).

Comment: **Most important** with `rufus` however is to only use *clones* of the ISO to your media... ie. do not use any options that cause re-formatting of the ISO.  Note `rufus` does **not** use terminology I'm using, I think it refers to *clone* as `dd-mode` with the `dd` being a simple copy from tape media days; ie. *dump data* to magnetic tape as `dd` does on modern GNU/Linux.